# jQuery max value of fields and min in form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dynamic

I'm little bit new with jQuery so I have some questions:

I have a form with 2 links where you can add 1 field and remove 1 field.

1. But the problem is I want to stop at 10 fields, so you max can add 10 fields?
2. The second problem is how can it stop at minimum 1 field, right now it's deleting every field to 0 if you click remove all the time?
3. Last question how can I do, so when I press submit button, I want to remember how many fields you were on before you pressed submit?

I hope somebody can help me, it's something i need really quick :-D

jQuery:

```
var i = $('input').size() + 1;
max = 10;

$('#add').click(function() {
    $('<div><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="Some text..." /></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
    i++;
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
if(i > 1) {
    $('.field:last').remove();
    i--; 
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="add">Add +1</a> | <a href="#" id="remove">Remove -1</a>
<form method="post">
    <div class="inputs">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="dynamic[]" class="field" value="Some text..."/></div>
        </div>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try something like `$('.field').length`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('.field').length` to get the amount of elements with the class 'field'(A more specific class name helps here). So if you use that class exclusively for the inputs you can use it as a solid count.

```
if ($('.field').length <= 10) {
    //Add a new one
} else {
    //Already 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#add').click(function() {
   if ($('.field').length <= 10) {
    $('<div><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="Some text..." /></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
    i++;
 }else
   alert("10 Completed");
});

$('#remove').click(function() {
  if ($('.field').length < 1) {
    $('.field:last').remove();
    i--; 
   }else
     alert("only one");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other two asnwers mine is same. Setup a fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Aq7rS/

```
var i = $('input').size() + 1;
max = 10;

$('#add').click(function() {

if($('.field').length < 11){
    $('<div><input type="text" class="field" name="dynamic[]" value="Some text..." /></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
        i++;
    }

});

$('#remove').click(function() {
    if($('.field').length > 1){
        if(i > 1) {
            $('.field:last').remove();
            i--; 
        }

    }
});
```